# Handling Exceptions in Flutter Non-Void Async Functions

Tags: flutter, dart, exception, error-handling

I'm working on a Dart/Flutter project, and I have a function that performs asynchronous operations using the `async/await` pattern. The function is designed to fetch data and handle errors gracefully.

Here's a simplified version of the code:

```
    Future<List<ChannelResponseModel>> getChannelList(BuildContext context) async {
      List<ChannelResponseModel> channels = [];
    
      final result = await _channelRepository.fetchChannelTimeStamp();
      result.fold(
        (error) {
          // What should I return here to satisfy the non-void return type?
        },
        (timeStamp) async {
          if (!isSameAsRemoteTimeStamp(timeStamp)) {
            channels = await _channelRepository.fetchOngoingChannels();
            state = state.copyWith(channelData: channels, dateData: timeStamp);
          }
          return state.listOfChannels;
        },
      );
    }
```

In the error callback, I'm not sure what to return to fulfill the non-void return type requirement. I want to handle errors gracefully and provide feedback to the user without breaking the function's return type.

1. What is the recommended approach for returning a non-void type in
   the error handling section?
2. Should I return a default value, throw an exception, or is there
   another best practice for such scenarios?

I appreciate any guidance or suggestions. Thank you for your help!

**Updated Solution**

```
  Future<List<ChannelResponseModel>> getChannelList() async {
    final result = await _channelRepository.fetchChannelTimeStamp();
    List<ChannelResponseModel> channels = [];

    return result.fold((error) {
      throw TimeoutException(error);
    }, (timeStamp) async {
      if (!isSameAsRemoteTimeStamp(timeStamp)) {
        channels = await _channelRepository.fetchOngoingChannels();
        state = state.copyWith(channelData: channels, dateData: timeStamp);
      }
      return state.listOfChannels;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Basically here I am using fpdart package which provide functional programming so while fetching it can either return exception string or else timestamp so by using fold method if its exception it will call first error function or else it will call timestamp function. And yes second callback is awaited

Comment: can you please elaborate little bit I am not getting what are you trying to say

Comment: well, you are calling `fold` method but not using its return value at all, instead you return always an empty list... did you try to `print` the value returned by `getChannelList` method?

Comment: yes sorry it was my fault but I have improved it now you can check my solution and let me know whether this is better solution or I can use somethin else.